# Retrieving rows where a set integer is > the count of an aggregate relation

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

Been having a bit of trouble with this one, getting pretty close but not quite there.  I have looked through other answers, and none quite seem to capture this.

There is a shared system for a library group with multiple locations, and the ultimate goal is to find a list of books which are in stock.  Each library member is a member of only one location, so although the system is shared, the inventories and subsequent checkouts which need to be compared are tied to a given location.

The relevant tables are as follows:

```
book_inventory (id, book_id, location_id, quantity)
membership (id, location_id, user_id)
book_checkout(id, membership_id, book_id, date_from, date_to)
```

Here's what I've come up with so far (with the ":locationid" replaced by the id of the location which should be looked up against), but it ignores rows where the COUNT() returns null.  So effectively, it returns all books which are in stock AND have one or more copies currently checked out.  It needs to return this AND any books which are in stock that do not have any copies checked out.

```
SELECT b.book_id, b.quantity FROM book_inventory b
LEFT JOIN book_checkout c ON c.book_id = b.book_id AND c.date_to IS NULL
INNER JOIN membership m ON m.id = c.membership_id AND m.location_id=:locationid
GROUP BY b.book_id HAVING b.quantity < COUNT(IFNULL(c.id, 0))
```

Thank you in advance for any insight!

Comment: Try removing Inner join with membership table, inner join will limit results to only those books having member ship id across there name and those only would be the ones which are checked out.

Comment: @PankajSanwal But he wants to check availability at that branch.

Comment: @Barmar For that Location_id filter should be moved to WHERE clause.

Comment: @PankajSanwal You can't do that because if the `LEFT JOIN` doesn't find anything, it will filter the entire row out.

Comment: @Barmar, I missed out on mentioning that Location_id column in where clause should be picked from book_inventory table and not from membership table.

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT(IFNULL(c.id, 0))` should be `IFNULL(COUNT(c.id), 0)`. The count will be NULL if no one has the book checked out.

You also need to `LEFT JOIN membership`, because you're joining with another table that was `LEFT JOINed`. `INNER JOIN` will cause the row to be removed from the result set if there was no `c.membership_id` to join with.

And `<` should be `>` to find the books that have more inventory than the number that were checked out. You can also subtract the count from `quantity` to get the remaining available copies, and check if that's more than 0.

```
SELECT b.book_id, b.quantity, b.quantity - IFNULL(COUNT(c.id), 0) AS available
FROM book_inventory b
LEFT JOIN book_checkout c ON c.book_id = b.book_id AND c.date_to IS NULL
LEFT JOIN membership m ON m.id = c.membership_id AND m.location_id=:locationid
GROUP BY b.book_id
HAVING available > 0
```

Comment: This works well but takes around 10 seconds to run.  

The tables have the following row counts:  
  
book_inventory - ~80,000  
membership - ~20,000  
book_checkout - ~350,000  
  
and there are fk on each of the ids which are being joined upon.  I added indexes to book_checkout.date_to and book_checkout.quantity, so everything being calculated or looked up against in this query is indexed.  
  
Is there any other optimization I can do here, or is my best bet to break this into smaller queries and recombine results programatically or use a view table?

Comment: Use `explain` to see if it's using the indexes. You might need multi-column indexes.